# POST requests without Content-Type header pass throught @Consumes check(In Jersey application)

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, web, jersey

We created Jersey service for client  with two classes, we used First class with Content type Multiple Part Form Data -- `@POST @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)` and in Second class we used only `@POST` as per our requirement. Service is working fine but client is hitting to Application without any content type so request is mapping with first class which lead to error.

As per my query it should match with 2nd class @POST if we do not use any content Type.

In 1st Class

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response submitForm(
```

In 2nd class

```
@POST
public Response submitForm(
```

QUESTION : POST requests without Content-Type header pass throught @Consumes check.

Comment: It has exact same resource URL?

Comment: *client is hitting to Application without any content type so request is mapping with first class which lead to error* can you clarify this statement ?

Comment: What happens if you add a `@Consumes("application/json")` annotation in the second class?

Comment: @POST@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response submitForm2(){return Response.accepted("plain POST").build();}    
@POST@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response submitForm(){return Response.accepted("Multipart Form POST").build();  } I tried with these methods in same resource class. Observed, If we send a request with out content-type header, the first occurrence of the method annotated with @POST is getting invoked. But a work around solution is as #braunpet mentioned try using application/json bcoz we don't have some thing like MediaType.nothing